# jsonファイル複数読み込みでキーポイントの取得

Tags: python, json

jsonファイルを読み込むときに複数読み込みたいのですが,キーポイントを指定すると読み込めなくなってしまいます.
以下にプログラムコードをのせます

```
import json

i = 000000000000

for file_name in ["right_{:012d}_keypoints.json".format(i) for i in range(6)]:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        print(read_data['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'])
```

エラー

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

またjson.road()を使って読み込もうとしたら、

```
import json

i = 000000000000

for file_name in ["right_{:012d}_keypoints.json".format(i) for i in range(6)]:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        read_data = json.road(f)
        print(read_data['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'])
```

エラー

```
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'road'
```

とでてしまいました。
何とかキーポイントを指定して複数のjsonファイルを読み込む方法はないでしょうか？
また、コメント欄での失礼な書き込み、大変申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: 単純なスペルミスですね。json.road ではなく json.load です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！お手数おかけしました！

Comment: @yoshiki 質問内容とニックネームから察するにアカウントが2つに分かれているように見えます。ヘルプを参考にして、アカウントの統合を検討してください。 - [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)